# Can you share private functions amongst mods within a crate?

Tags: rust

I'm building out a crate and for use across several applications I'm working on. At the moment, I have a handful of functions that serve as 'helpers' for the rest of the crate which I would like to expose across my crate but not to the applications. Is there a way to do this? A middle ground between public and private?

example:

```
// lib.rs
pub mod mod_a;
pub mod mod_b;
```

```
// mod_a.rs, mod_b.rs
use helpers::bar;

pub fn foo() {
   bar()
}

...
```

```
// helpers.rs
pub fn bar(x: i64) {
   return(x+1)
}
```

I would like to expose the function `bar` to `mod_a` and `mod_b`, without exporting it from my crate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pub(crate)` while declaring items.